# If $\{T(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ is an uniformly continuous semigroup of bounded linear operators then $T(s)\to T(t)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators

> **Definition:** Let $X$ be a Banach space and $I$ the identity operator on $X$. A family $\{T(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ of bounded linear operators from $X$ into $X$ is a *semigroup of bounded linear operator on* $X$ if
>
> (i) $T(0)=I$;
>   (ii) $T(t + s)= T(t)T(s)$ for every $t,s\geq 0$.
>
> A semigroup $\{T(t)\}_{t\geq0}$ of bounded linear operators is *uniformly continuous* if $$\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\|T(t)-I\|=0.\;\;\;\;(*)$$

The [Pazy's book](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=1YWmMAEACAAJ&dq=Semigroups%20of%20Linear%20Operators%20and%20Applications%20to%20Partial%20Differential%20Equations&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=SVhKUqDyL43s8gTftYDICw&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA) says "from the definition it's clear that if $\{T(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ is an uniformly continuous semigroup of bounded linear operators then $\lim_{s\to t}\|T(s)-T(t)\|=0$" (page 1).

For me, this equality it's not so clear. Could someone help me to prove it? I'm trying to show that $$\lim_{s\to t^+}\|T(s)-T(t)\|=\lim_{s\to t^-}\|T(s)-T(t)\|=0.$$

If I'm not wrong, from the definition we can conclude that, for all $h>0$,

$$0\leq \|T(t+h)-T(t)\| \overset{(ii)} =\|T(t)T(h)-T(t)\| \leq \|T(t)\|\|T(h)-I\|$$

Now, notice that

$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\|T(t)\|\|T(h)-I\|=\|T(t)\|\lim_{h\downarrow 0}\|T(h)-I\|
\overset{(*)}=\|T(t)\|\;0=0$$

Thus (by Squeeze theorem),

$$\lim_{s\to t^+}\|T(s)-T(t)\| =\lim_{h\to 0^+}\|T(t+h)-T(t)\| = 0$$

**My question is:** how to prove that $\lim_{s\to t^-}\|T(s)-T(t)\|=0$?

Thanks.

Comment: You have $T(t - h) - T(t) = T(t - h)(I - T(h))$. Can you show that $\|T(t - h)\|$ is bounded for all $h$?

Comment: @ABlumenthal What means $T(t-h)$ when $h>t$? From the definition, $T(t-h)$ makes sense only if $t-h\geq 0$. So, what do you mean by "for all $h$"?

Comment: I should clarify: I mean, can you show that $\|T (t - h)\|$ is bounded for all sufficiently small $h$. The argument only makes sense when $t > 0$ and $t > h$.

Comment: @ABlumenthal From the definition $\|T(s)\|$ is bounded for all $s\geq 0$. Particularly, $\|T(t-h)\|$ is bounded for all $t-h\geq 0$, that is, for all sufficiently small $h$. Is it correct? If so, what's the next step of your argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\Vert T(t)-I\Vert\to 0\,$ as $t\to 0^+$, one can find $\delta >0$ such that $\Vert T(t)\Vert\leq 2$ for all $t\in [0,\delta]$.
By the semigroup property, it follows that $(T(t))$ is uniformly bounded on any compact interval $[0,A]$. Indeed, if $n\in\mathbb N$ is such that $n\delta>A$, then $\Vert T(t)\Vert\leq 2^n$ on $[0,n\delta]$ and hence on $[0,A]$.

Now, fix $t_0>0$, and choose $C$ such that $\Vert T(t)\Vert\leq C$ on $[0,t_0]$. For any $t\in [0, t_0]$ you can write $T(t)-T(t_0)=T(t)\left (I-T(t_0-t)\right)\, ,$ so that  $$\Vert T(t)-T(t_0)\Vert\leq \Vert T(t)\Vert\, \Vert I-T(t_0-t)\Vert\, \leq C\, \Vert I-T(t_0-t)\Vert\, .$$ Since $T(t_0-t)\to I$ as $t\to t_0^-$, this shows continuity on the left at $t_0$.

Comment: This applies only to $t_0>0$?

Comment: For $t_0=0$, continuity on the left is not really meaningful...

Comment: Etienne: Thanks very much, I misread the problem.  (Don't know how I missed all the clues; I was thinking of a group instead of a semigroup, hence my off answer, now deleted.)

Comment: You're welcome!